# c++ huge performance difference by just one line of code

Tags: c++, performance

Here is some background of the code.

I'm working on a project which is able to flash ECUs via CAN bus, this CAN_TransferData will be called 768 times, `CAN_messageProc(&msg, cut_data);` is what actually drives the hardware to send messages on CAN bus.

The whole flashing process on my computer takes 61 seconds, but on another computer, it takes 92 seconds. If I change `ctrl` to a constant(i.e. 7), the process would also take about 61 seconds on the second computer.

Also, most the time this function is called, the only thing changes is `ctrl`, so I though it was because the changing `ctrl` disables the compiler to optimize the code, but this can't explain why does this code runs faster on the first machine.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

PS: I'm using vs2010's cpp compiler

```
int CAN_protocol::CAN_TransferData(U32 CANNo, U8 ctrl, U32 len)
{
    int result;
    CAN_msg msg;
    U16 lenth;

    lenth = (U16)len + 2;
    memset(msg.data, 0xff, 8);
    msg.id= 0x7E0;
    msg.data[0] =(0x10 | (lenth >> 8));
    msg.data[1] = lenth & 0xff;
    msg.data[2] = 0x36;
    msg.data[3] = ctrl; // change ctrl to 0 here will significantly increase execute speed.
    memcpy(&msg.data[4], &cut_data[1], 4);
    msg.len = 8;
    msg.ch = 1;
    msg.format = CAN_ID_FORMAT_STANDARD;
    msg.type = CAN_FRAME_TYPE_DATA;

    result = CAN_messageProc(&msg, cut_data);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Without knowing anything about CAN message-bus, my assumption is that changing `ctrl` to `0` performs a different command, or something invalid.  What is the the significance of `ctrl`?

Comment: There has to be something else going on.

Comment: @Matthew it's just a byte, used to indicate which step is the current process.

Comment: In your question you say that changing the line `msg.data[3] = ctrl;` to `msg.data[3] = 0;` causes the program to execute faster.  The problem does not lie with that specific line, the problem is how `CAN_messageProc` interprets the now different `msg` argument.  That is what I meant by the significance of the change.  If you call `CAN_TransferData` where the `ctrl` param is `0`, I'm sure you'll see identical results in your testing.

Comment: slightly off topic, but your `memset(msg.data, 0xff, 8);` line is superfluous.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that msg.data is not of type U8 and is being expanded? The best way to tell if my hypothesis is correct is to post the generated assembly for both with ctrl and with the constant.

Comment: That would imply that expanding was taking 39 msecs (30/768.)  Something is seriously broken if that's true.  This is almost certainly something about what CAN_messageProc is doing.

Comment: I was assuming the function was being called millions of times. Yes you are right something strange is happening. I would like to see the source code of CAN_messageProc